# Show Data tabel grocery CRUD based User login ion auth in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

Everyone have ides about showing data tabel grocery CRUD based user login.

This I have function

```
public function get_all()
{

    $user = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id();

    if ($user == 1 ) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('Customers');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();

    } else {
                $this->db->where('id_user',$user);
                $this->db->from('Customers');

                $query = $this->db->get();

                return $query->result();


            }

}
```

The code above, I want to apply to Grocery Crud, so when the user logs in, the data displayed only matches the user ID that is logged in.

This format the tabel

`'Customers' => 'id', 'id_user', 'name', 'address', 'number_phone','collage'`

And every time add data, will automatically create a user id number based user login in the 'id_user' field.

Please help..
Best Regards

Luqman El-Jupiter

Answer (score 0):

To select only specific column, you could use the `where` function provided by grocery CRUD :

```
public function get_all()
{

    $user = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id();

    if ($user == 1 ) {
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
        $crud->set_table('Customers');
        $crud->order_by('id');

        $output = $crud->render();
        $this->_view_output($output);

    } else {
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        $crud->where('id_user',$user);

        $crud->set_table('Customers');
        $crud->order_by('id');

        $output = $crud->render();
        $this->_view_output($output);
    }

}
```